# cant float div box right

Tags: html, css

im working on a new website right now and i have there a lil problem.

I have a slider at the main paige and at the top of it , is a small banner . Its right now on the left site at the top of the slider and i would like to have it on the right site but i dont know how.

Float right didnt work.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <script src="//www.jameda.de/premium/widgets/getwidget.php?id=81323170&amp;art=1&amp;badge=17252" type="text/javascript" async></script>
    <div id="jameda-widget-container17252" style="position:absolute; width:97px; height:145px; margin:0px; z-index:100;margin-left:-3px;background-image:url(//www.jameda.de/premium/widgets/_images/bw-small-bg.png); background-repeat:none; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:15px;">
        <a href="http://www.jameda.de/berlin/aerzte/hautaerzte-dermatologen-geschlechtskrankheiten/fachgebiet/?utm_content=BWnote&amp;utm_source=Kunden-Homepages&amp;utm_medium=Badges&amp;utm_term=81323170&amp;utm_campaign=Badges" id="jam_link_check" style="display:block; position:absolute; top:100px; left:10px; width:70px; height:20px; background-color:transparent !important;"
        target="_blank"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

thats the html code from the banner wich i would like to have on the right side . [Test site](http://www.awesom-media.de/arzt/)

Comment: You should really be pressing CTRL-U in your browser and sending the source code appearing therein (the code as it is sent to your browser after PHP has executed. As it stands, nobody can tell what the PHP generates inside the script tag and thus nobody can tell what the generated JavaScript is doing.

Comment: As it stands, all I can suggest is changing the CSS that says left: to right: . Hopefully the container will occupy the width of the whole screen, otherwise apply something like say, width: 400px on the container if you want the area within which to place your tag to be narrower.

Comment: without the CSS...no concrete answer can be provided..please add the styling part!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple add `position:relative;` in wrapper class and `right:0;` in div(#jameda-widget-container17252). it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `position:relative` to the `wrapper` class and `right:0;` to the badge you are using.

Here is the below code which will work for you. I dont recommend inline style. But you can then write it in separate stylesheet

```
<div class="wrapper" style="position:relative;">
    <script src="//www.jameda.de/premium/widgets/getwidget.php?id=81323170&amp;art=1&amp;badge=17252" type="text/javascript" async></script>
    <div id="jameda-widget-container17252" style="position:absolute; right:0; width:97px; height:145px; margin:0px; z-index:100;margin-left:-3px;background-image:url(//www.jameda.de/premium/widgets/_images/bw-small-bg.png); background-repeat:none; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:15px;">
        <a href="http://www.jameda.de/berlin/aerzte/hautaerzte-dermatologen-geschlechtskrankheiten/fachgebiet/?utm_content=BWnote&amp;utm_source=Kunden-Homepages&amp;utm_medium=Badges&amp;utm_term=81323170&amp;utm_campaign=Badges" id="jam_link_check" style="display:block; position:absolute; top:100px; left:10px; width:70px; height:20px; background-color:transparent !important;"
        target="_blank"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if an element has 'position:absolute' and it can't be floated.
(float - It may be set for any element, but only applies to elements that generate boxes that are not absolutely positioned. http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/float)

add css like this;

```
.wrapper { position: relative; }
#jameda-widget-container17252 { right: 0; }
```